# Android Studio - Unable to run application on virtual device

Tags: java, android, device, virtual

i am total newbie into android studio and java.
Could you give me some advice how to fix these errors? I am using older android studio because of the tutorials I am following, the guy has this version so to keep it as simple as it can get, I am trying to stay on the same version (1.0.0)

EDIT: I am unable to post pictures, so I will just paste the error code lines here.

**Gradle**

```
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command C:\Users\sh4rp_000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

**My configuration:**

Compile Sdk Version: API 21: Android 5.0 (Lollipop)
Build tools version: 21.1.2

**Virtual device**

I was unable to create the virtual device, because I was unable to proceed to the "creation" screen, due to mentioned errors.

Comment: Please read [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the virtual device also?

Comment: Either Use Geny Motion Emulator which works fine and less hassle or upgrade Android Studio because the issue might be resolved in the newer version, It is not big issue if you follow an old tutorial. Your code will work fine until you use same android SDK and API's

Comment: When are you getting this error, exactly?

Comment: @ZeusInTexas
When I click the little play button and after like 10 seconds it fails.

Comment: @Sharpen so you got past creating your Android Virtual Device, didn't you?
AFAIK (but to be honest, I don't use Android Studio a lot), the virtual device has to exist before actually running an app on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Android studio fixed the problem and didn't bring up any errors while following tutorial of older version android studio.

Thanks for all the help.